# Annotate a function return type with an instance, not a type

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

I would like to type a function to an actual object, not the type of this object, and the type checker to understand this.

Imagine this example:

```py
my_marker = "This is very singletony, I promise!"

def get_object_or_a_singleton_marker() -> int|my_marker: # invalid syntax
  if (some_condition_is_met):
    return some_int_value() 
  else:
    return my_marker # singleton

a_var = get_object_or_a_singleton_marker()

if a_var is not my_marker:
   # I want the type to be narrowed here
```

For the record, here the singleton is a string, but in my real code, it would be a class instance.

The example as written is invalid, because `my_marker` is not a type expression.
Using `Literal[my_marker]` has the same issue.

If I use `type[my_marker]` as annotation, then the narrowing will not work (in my example, the variable will not be `my_marker` but could be any other `str`)

I could probably use a `TypeGuard` function, but the idea is to keep the syntax as is, ie. with the use of `is`, without any other boilerplate.

Can I annotate a function with an instance, not a type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround would be to make the singleton object the value of an `Enum`, so you can type a function with it in a `typing.Literal`:

```
from typing import Literal
from enum import Enum
from random import random

class MyMarker(Enum):
    MARKER = "This is very singletony, I promise!"

def get_object_or_a_singleton_marker() -> int | Literal[MyMarker.MARKER]:
    if random() < 0.5:
        return 1
    else:
        return MyMarker.my_marker

a_var = get_object_or_a_singleton_marker()

if a_var is not MyMarker.MARKER:
    pass
```

Demo: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=76062ce158f1d56a3d8c996209ad5a7e